# Overwatch competitive points reward at season (4) end

Tags: overwatch

As you probably already know, you get competitive points after winning or tying a match. When you get 3k of those CP you can buy a golden weapon.

When a competitive season ends, you get a reward based on your rank. The thing that I want to know is, possibly with a link to an official thread, if this reward is based on the season high or the current rank that you end with.

Example: I'm a master right now (between 3500 and 4000) and if I end like so I should get 2k CP.

If I drop under 3500 and go back to diamond (since from master and above you can actually derank) will I still get 2k or 1.2k CP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Points you get are based on the Season High. You can be 1k now, but if you were 4500 at one point, you'll get the rewards for 4500. ([old source](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753177912))

The only difference from old seasons is **you need to be Top 500 at the end of the season** ([source](http://overwatch.metabomb.net/news/overwatch-season-4-skill-ratings)) to get the top 500 rewards, whereas previously you only needed to have been in top 500 at any point in the season. I'll post resource in a second.

They haven't made the announcement yet on the forums, so there's no official statement on that but it is widely known in the community the above to be true. Ill update my answer with the Announcement thread when they post it in the forums.

Comment: I have rolled back the edit, don't put words in the author's mouth

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Emh... what? I'm just trying to provide the best information so that future visitors can quickly read in one single post (the best answer). Isn't that the spirit of the whole stack exchange community?

Comment: @MattiaNocerino No, that's not how edits work. Post a comment or make a new answer.

Comment: Ok then. If you get banned at the end of the season, you won't get any cp! Source: a friend of mine

Answer (score 0):

You will get the rewards based on the maximum SR you get on the entire season.
So, If your maximum SR are 4000 and you are right now with 3500, your reward will be 4000.

Official forum of Overwatch:

> Aside from sprays and icons, you’ll also receive a number of Competitive Points based on the maximum skill rating you achieved during the season

Source: [Overwatch official forum](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753177912)

The Source is from the Rewards of the Season 3. But, right now is the same as Season 2 to Season 4.

Comment: How is gamepedia an official source? I know that what's written there is probably true, but they must get the information from somewhere else because it's a third party website. What if they changed something and the information is not updated?

Comment: My bad, I just think the gamepedia was the official wiki, I just updated with the correct info and source.

Comment: Don't worry, thanks for the help. I have to accept @Иво Недев 's answer because he was faster but i upvoted you anyway (but somebody has downvoted you, don't know why)

Comment: It happens, I received so many downvotes I don't know why, but no problem I just want to help people in my favourite games :)